# SQL - delimiting + matching

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the follow columns:
reportid, reportname, startdate, consolidated

Reports which are consolidated do not have a start date.

What I need to do is to find the earliest start date within the subreports and set it as the start date

For example

```
report  reportname  startdate  consolidated
1       ABC         2019/1/1   1
2       DEF                    3,4
3       GHI         2019/4/1   3
4       JKF         2019/5/1   4
```

The report may be consolidated from any number of reports (ie. report 10 may consist of 11,12,13 while report 20 may consist of only 21 and 22)

Output required

```
report  reportname  startdate  consolidated
1       ABC         2019/1/1   1
2       DEF         2019/4/1   3,4
3       GHI         2019/4/1   3
4       JKF         2019/5/1   4
```

I can only think of pulling each number and looping through the entire list, comparing each date that is picked up as I go. However, this list is very very long which doesn't make it very feasible.

Thanks in advance!

---

Unfortunately, I do not have the authority to adjust the database where these tables are concerned.

Comment: Do you think about make table with relations instead `consolidated` column?

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your data model.  Storing multiple values in a string is wrong.  Storing numbers in a string is wrong.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other peoples really, really bad decisions.  You can do what you want, but it is more complicated than necessary:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(startdate) over (partition by s.value) as imputed_startdate,
             row_number() over (partition by report order by report) as seqnum
      from t outer apply
           string_split(t.consolidated, ',') s 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1bddd161d160d75b1f7fffae4778f64d) is a db<>fiddle.